# How to list all forms of solution explorer in property of custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a login validation custom control. It has two properties named `username` and `password`, which are showed in properties window when included in the project.

I want to create a property which will show all forms list in a ComboBox-like manner to the properties window, so that the project programmer can specify which form will be open when login successful. The custom control has two textboxes and one button. How should I do it?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private string uname=null;
        private string pword=null;

        public string username
        {
            get
            {
                return uname;

            }
            set
            {
                uname = value;

            }

        }
        public string password
        {
            get
            {
                return pword;
            }
            set
            {
                pword=value;
            }
        }


        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == username && textBox2.Text == password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login successful");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("wrong password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `Forms` in the current executing `Module`, you can do something like this:

```
//Must add using System.Reflection; first    
public class LoginForm : Form {
  public LoginForm(){
     InitializeComponent(); 
     Load += (s,e) => {
        forms = GetAllForms();
        comboBox1.DataSource = forms;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";//Show the caption
     }; 
  }
  List<Form> forms;
  public List<Form> GetAllForms(){
    List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();
    foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].GetTypes())
    {
      if (t == GetType()) continue;//Don't add LoginForm
      if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)))
      {
         forms.Add((Form)t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null));
      }
    }
    return forms;
  }
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (textBox1.Text == username && textBox2.Text == password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login successful");
            //Show the selected form
            forms[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Show();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("wrong password");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> so that the project programmer can specify which form will be open when login successful

That really is not the task of your usercontrol. Maybe the programmer wants to do something else upon a successful login.

Create a `LoggedIn` event which you fire upon a successful login, and subscribe to that event from the code where you use the control. The programmer can then, in that event handler, do as he or she desires.